# Particles.js with images imported in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles, particles.js

I just can't make it work, images work normally in my React app when I import them like this:

```
import logo from '../Assets/logo.png';
```

But with Particles.js I can't make it work. My code:

```
 shape: {
        type: 'images',
        images: [
          {
            src: logo,
            height: 20,
            width: 23,
          }]}
```

and I tried

```
src: '../Assets/logo.png',
src: {logo},
src: logo,
url: '../Assets/logo.png',
url: {logo},
url: logo,
```

Only way to make it work is to do something like this:

```
src: 'https://www.someexternalsource.com/download/icon/1537041'
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change `images: [` to `image: [` and it worked....